# JavaScript: Sound not looping on Firefox (Phone/Tablet)

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, mobile

I cannot for the life of me get the sound to loop on Firefox at all. I've searched Google for hours and I still feel like I'm asking a stupid question, which there is an answer out there. Any help at all is highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

**Here is what I have tried:**

```
var newJobAudio = new Audio('/audio/newjobalert.mp3');
    newJobAudio.loop = true;
    newJobAudio.play();
```

**Edit: Updated code (doesn't work still, but, just so everyone can see what I have)**

```
var newJobAudio = new Audio('/audio/newjobalert.mp3');

audioLoop(true);

    function audioLoop(play) {
    if ( play ) {
        newJobAudio.addEventListener('ended', playAudio, false);
        newJobAudio.play();
    } else {
        newJobAudio.removeEventListener('ended', playAudio, false);
        newJobAudio.pause();
    }
}

function playAudio() {
    newJobAudio.currentTime = 0;
    newJobAudio.play();
}
```

**Edit:**

Even though tablet/phone Firefox works fine with mp3 the sound breaks after the first play. I was able to determine this by using a workaround for sound looping using setInterval. When setInterval started looping every 2 sec the sound would play fine first time but would break on the others. Rustam thanks you very much for all the help mate! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newJobAudio1 = new Audio('/audio/newjobalert.mp3');
var newJobAudio2 = new Audio('/audio/newjobalert.mp3');

newJobAudio1.addEventListener('ended', function(){
this.currentTime = 0;
this.pause();
newJobAudio2.play();
}, false);

newJobAudio2.addEventListener('ended', function(){
this.currentTime = 0;
this.pause();
newJobAudio1.play();
}, false);

newJobAudio1.play(); // start playing
```

Use 2 audios and they will switch each other

Comment: That's weird because the sound plays without issue on Firefox, though, it **doesn't** loop.

Comment: I've tried the code above just now, but, even though it loops on my desktop it doesn't loop on my tablet or phone (all are using Firefox).

Comment: code updated, try to add this.play(); after it is setted to currentTime = 0

Comment: No dice still. Works like a charm on the desktop just refuses to budge on phone and tablet. I want to cry! haha. By the way, thank you very much for taking your time in helping me!

Comment: can you check on your phone or tablet what is the output of typeof newJobAudio.loop?

Comment: It's `boolean`! Now this is getting weirder! If it's coming up as `boolean` it should most def. loop, but, only plays it ones. *Bangs head against table*

Comment: hmmmm maybe because you are start playing it before adding the eventListener?, also try to make it as an html <audio loop>, without creating it dynamically, also do you see any errors in your firefox console?

Comment: I've moved the play() after the eventListener and nothing still. I also tried `<audio loop>` as well without any luck on the phone and tablet like always it works on desktop. I've got no errors on the phone or tablet in the JS.

Comment: Even though tablet/phone Firefox works fine with `mp3` the sound breaks after the first play. I was able to determine this by using a workaround for sound looping using `setInterval`. When `setInterval` started looping every 2 sec the sound would play fine first time but would break on the others. Rustam thanks you very much for all the help mate! =)

Comment: finally you can try to use this library https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js, some examples http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library

Comment: Last update didn't work per se, but, it lead me to the answer and because of all the help I thought it's just fair to at least award you the answer :)